xpad notes move place on startup
I have Xpad set to launch at startup (Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS). When Ubuntu launches the notes appear in the middle of my desktop - I manually drag them to the side, but whenever I shut down and start up the system, they're in the middle again. How can I fix this so that the notes stay pasted in the same place?
